# Calling a windows program with a BATCH file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I am testing out batch files and I am trying to launch notepad.exe but without any success.

test.bat:

```
@echo off
START /MAX "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

the only thing that happens is that a new command prompt window opens up with "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" as its title.

any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

CMD's silly parsing goes on :)

Remove the `""` and CMD won't assume you try to set the title of the new window.

Or, use:

```
START /MAX "" "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: but what if you want to run a program inside Program(space bar)Files... It won't know that it is inside Program Files

Comment: That's why you use the second form, with an extra "" that CMD treats as a window title, followed by the quoted "C:\Path To\The file.exe"

Answer (score 2):

You can just call ...

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

Comment: That doesn't maximize, he needs start /max

Comment: Fair enough, I've been beaten to the alternative, so I'll just keep quiet (and give the rightful winner a +1)

Answer (score 0):

what about just

```
@echo off
"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your command like this then it opens a notepad maximized: (no double quotes)

```
START /MAX C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```